# .net xml serialization - checking file before parsing

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I use the following code to serialize xml file.

I wonder whether should I use the `CanDeserialize` function in this case.

I noticed that `CanDeserialize` throws `XmlException` if the file is empty.

`Deserialize` throws `InvalidOperationException` in that case.

My question is should I remove that extra check and if `Deserialize` does some sort of check anyway?

EDIT: After reading some comments and answers, I wonder when to use `CanDeserialize` ?

```
public static T RestoreFromXml(string filename)
{
    Object res = null;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        try
        {
            if (xs.CanDeserialize(reader))
            {
                res = xs.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
        catch (XmlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }            
    }
    return (T)res;
}
```

Comment: an empty file is not a valide file to deserialize, I think you have to test if the file is empty and then put your try/catch code.

Comment: I guess you can decide that based on what level of information you want back - if you want to tell the user that the file is empty, check the file first. Otherwise, just use `Deserialize`. Personally, I've never used `CanDeserialize` before the `Deserialize` call, because the InnerException of the Exception thrown from Deserialize is pretty explanatory

Comment: One char in file - {"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}
Empty file - {"Root element is missing."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some checkings before trying to deserialize - check if the file name is not null or empty, check if the file exists, etc. Here's some code to deserialize a file:

```
/// <summary>
/// XML serializer helper class. Serializes and deserializes objects from/to XML
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to serialize/deserialize.
/// Must have a parameterless constructor and implement <see cref="Serializable"/></typeparam>
public class XmlSerializer<T> where T: class, new()
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The filename of the XML file to deserialize</param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T DeserializeFromFile(string filename)
    {
        return DeserializeFromFile(filename, new XmlReaderSettings());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes a XML file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">The filename of the XML file to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="settings">XML serialization settings. <see cref="System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings"/></param>
    /// <returns>An object of type <c>T</c></returns>
    public static T DeserializeFromFile(string filename, XmlReaderSettings settings)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            throw new ArgumentException("filename", "XML filename cannot be null or empty");

        if (! File.Exists(filename))
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find XML file to deserialize", filename);

        // Create the stream writer with the specified encoding
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename, settings))
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T) xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

}

You can use it like this:

```
string filename = "...";

Foo foo = XmlSerializer<Foo>.DeserializeFromFile(filename);
```

This code was taken from an article that I wrote, you can find it here:

[XML serialization using Generics](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233908/Xml-serialization-using-generics)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use CanDeserialize just to throw as few exceptions as possible. Exceptions should be for when the application is in an abnormal state that you can't protect yourself from.

You could say the same thing about guards. 
Why check:

```
if (value == null)
    return;
//do something
```

instead of:

```
try{
   // do something
catch()
```

It's not the exact same thing but I think the general idea of keeping your application as free from exceptions as you can manage is a good idea.

Comment: Agreed.  I just ran a performance test against checking vs. catching exceptions and catching exceptions took a very long time(never completed actually) and maxed my CPU core.  The checking only took a couple seconds.